# Create video from images, add audio and animation within images without FFMPEG in Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I want to **create a video from multiple images without using FFMPEG in Android**. Also i have to multiple audios over it. And at last there should be some animation within each images. I have tried this using FFMPEG, but it is taking hell lot of time, let say , 4-5 min for 10 photos. Is there any other way for this or any efficient way?

There is 3 way process.

1. First i create video from each image with audio and added text.
2. Then i concatenate all the videos into a single video.
3. At last, i add a background audio to the concatenated video.

I am sharing the commands here:

> 1.
>   String[] cmds = {"-y"
>                       , "-r", "1", "-vcodec", "mjpeg" ,"-loop", "1", "-t", "1"
>                       , "-i", image
>                       , "-i", audio
>                       , "-vf"
>                       , "zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1),1.1,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125,drawbox=y=ih/PHI:color=black@0.4:width=iw:height=120:t=max,drawtext=fontfile=/storage/emulated/0/ffmpeg/font.ttf:text="+text+":fontcolor=white:fontsize=60:x=(w-tw)/2:y=(h/PHI)+th"
>                       , "-c:v", "libx264"
>                       , "-preset", "ultrafast", "-t", "5", "-c:a", "aac", "-b:a", "128k", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p"
>                       , "video1.mp4"};

2.

> String cmd = "-y -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp4 -filter_complex concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 -preset ultrafast concat_video.mp4;

3.

> cmd = "-y -i bg_audio.mp3 -i concat_video.mp4 -shortest -preset ultrafast -filter_complex [a1][a2]amerge,pan=stereo:c0

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I have updated the question

Comment: You should be able to do everything in one command. That would speed it up. Also, show the complete console output from one of the commands.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard how can i combine these 3 commands into one? Can you guide me through?

Comment: Not possible to provide answer without knowing anything about your `ffmpeg` and each input. Show the complete output of: `ffmpeg -i image -i -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp4 -i bg_audio.mp3`

Comment: @LordNeckbeard can we connect somewhere for discussion?